# How to collect list of background process PIDs launched in bash for loop in a single line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The following bash script forks several processes in a loop, collecting all of their PIDs along the way, and then waits for them all to finish:

```
PIDS=''
for i in $(seq 1 3); do  
  ./longRunningProcess & 
  PIDS=$PIDS' '$!
done

wait $PIDS
```

This works fine when entered in bash line by line, however I want to execute this for loop on a single line, which I thought should be the following:

```
for i in $(seq 1 3); do ./longRunningProcess & PIDS=$PIDS' '$!; done
```

But when I try to execute this, I get:

```
-bash: !: event not found
```

It seems that bash is somehow interpreting the ! as a command history expansion, but I would have thought that the preceding `$` would change its interpretation to the PID of the last forked background process.

I would like to understand:

1. Why bash is interpreting the `!` in this way
2. What is the correct way of writing it, and why

Thanks!

Comment: The single line is not the problem. The "at the prompt" is the problem. Disable history expansion at your prompt and it will work. Write it as a single line in the script and it'll work too. History expansion is dumb. Using `PIDS=$PIDS' '$! ;` might work.

Comment: Yup, the added space after `!` worked, as it disabled the interpretation of the `!` as a command history expansion. It seems, then, that the reason why this worked in the multi-line case is that the character following `!` is a carriage return, so bash does not interpret it as a command history expansion. And further, command history expansion occurs before `$` variable value substitution. Is that right?

Comment: I would tend to suggest `PIDS="${PIDS} $!"` as an alternative...

Comment: @twalberg That would not solve the problem, because the `"` following the `!` causes `!` to still be interpreted as a command history expansion. I believe what you meant to say was: `for i in $(seq 1 3); do ./longRunningProcess & PIDS="${PIDS} $! "; done`. This will work, because the `!` is followed by a space.

Comment: @ellitron History expansion is not done inside double quotes, so the extra space at the end is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

History expansion is dumb.

The problem isn't the single line the problem is history expansion being enabled (mostly).

Disabling history expansion in your interactive shell will make this work.

Putting the single line in a script (where history expansion is disabled by default) will also work.

The combination of history expansion and the single-line causes the expansion to be attempted and explode.

Doing this on multiple lines in the shell will *also* fail though (if you leave the semi-colons intact... more on that in a second).

The [History Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction) section of the bash reference manual explains how the command line is scanned for history expansion like this:

> History expansions are introduced by the appearance of the history expansion character, which is ‘!’ by default. Only ‘\’ and ‘'’ may be used to escape the history expansion character.

The [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) adds (and I'm not sure why the reference manual doesn't say this):

> Several characters inhibit history expansion if found immediately following the history expansion character, even if it is unquoted: space, tab, newline, carriage return, and =. If the extglob shell option is enabled, ( will also inhibit expansion.

So adding a space/etc. after the `!` in that single-line version should work.